# Увеличение модального окна FancyBox на сенсорных устройствах

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, fancybox

Собственно в чем вопрос, можно ли увеличить на сенсорных устройствах двумя пальцами модальное окно FancyBox, я попробовал и inline и ajax, не получилось.

есть такой viewport `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1200, user-scalable=yes">`, думаю что возможно стилями что-то получится, но пока никак.

Знает кто что??

Comment: Как связаны с вопросом "inline и ajax"?

Comment: FancyBox может сделать модальное окно inline HTML  или ajax, а при том что на сайте с примерами http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#inline открытое окно inline не увеличивается двумя пальцами, а в ajax окне получается